# draw path on indoor map using geoJSON avoiding obstacles

Tags: geojson, web-mapping, android, shortest-path, indoor

I'm a CS student and right now I'm developing an android app that uses google maps API, the problem is the map I'm working on is indoor and I'm facing problems when I want to draw a path from user location to specific location he chose because Directions API doesn't work with indoor map and when using a drawPolyLine method it draws a line that passes through walls, bathrooms, and anything on its way,, so to solve this problem I made a GeoJSON file with linestring and polygon of each obstacle in that map..

and now I want to use the available drawing methods along with the geoJSON file to read the points/polygon and avoid it while drawing the path on the map, I searched a lot before asking and seeking for help but didn't find anything helpful and the deadline of the project is 2 weeks from now,

could please give an idea or anything that could solve my issue?

Comment: some more details on indoor mapping in android using google maps http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/mappingDemo.html

Comment: You may have a look at [turf.js](http://turfjs.org). It has a [shortest path function](http://turfjs.org/docs#shortestPath) which avoids defined obstacles.

Comment: Look into graphhopper.